# problem recording tweets on a given topic

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

I would like to point out that I already know how to save a user's tweets in a file. Now my problem is that I would like to be able to save the tweets of a given topic in a file.

The problem is that as soon as I try to "convert" the program, I get the error "Status" object is not iterable as below:

Thanks to those who will be able to help :)

```
search_word = input("subject ? \n")

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = search_word, lang = "en", since = "2019-04-01").items(3000):
    z = [x for x in tweet]
    with open('%s_tweets.json' % search_word, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(z, out)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TheoLC/Desktop/python/twitter_search/collect+200tw.py", line 17, in <module>
    z = [x for x in tweet]
TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you show the earlier code that was working?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're hoping to do with the code above. There are quite a few things that don't fit together for someone looking at only a snippet, so I've got a few examples to help in a couple of things you ***may*** be trying to do.

---

The reason your current code is failing, is because you're trying to iterate over a Status object with your `z=` line. This object is JSON like in structure. You can see an example of this [here](https://gist.github.com/dev-techmoe/ef676cdd03ac47ac503e856282077bf2).

This means that you have to access particular attributes in order to iterate over them, you can't iterate over the object itself. For example, if you wanted to get the text from a tweet, you could change your line to:

```
z = [x for x in tweet.text]
```

---

If you're trying to just get the entirety of information of the tweet into a JSON file (i.e the Status object into a JSON file), then you don't need to iterate over it at all, you could just `json.dump()` the object. To do this, remove your `z=` line, and change your json dump line to

```
json.dump(tweet._json, out)
```

Leaving your code as:

```
search_word = input("subject ? \n")

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = search_word, lang = "en", since = "2019-04-01").items(3000):
    with open('%s_tweets.json' % search_word, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(tweet._json, out)
```

---

Hope that helps. (You've not asked about this, but as an addendum, I think the amount you have in `.items()` may be too high. I think the API limits will force you to reduce this).